# How do i get Gps location and send it using sms as google maps link

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm developing an app that if an emergency arises it will send an emergency message and location.
So far managed to send just a message but still stuck to get my location and send it.
Anyone can help?

Comment: Use fused location manager for the current location.https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current

Comment: Okay I'll try it